# Create CSS3 Circles with text inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to add text inside a CSS3 circle. But the text is outside of the circles proportion. When I hover over the circle it changes color but I would also like for the text to dissapear as well.

Extras: Is there a way to create make the circle pulsate while mouse is over it? Will jquery or javascript be necessary?

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/jqEzZ/2/

```
<style>

.cn-nav > a{
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
height: 70px;
width: 70px;
}
a.cn-nav-prev{
left: 0px;
}
a.cn-nav-next{
right: 0px;
}

.cn-nav a span{
width: 46px;
height: 46px;
display: block;
text-indent: -9000px;
-moz-border-radius: 23px;
-webkit-border-radius: 23px;
border-radius: 23px;
cursor: pointer;
opacity: 0.9;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
background-size: 17px 25px;
margin: -23px 0 0 -23px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.cn-nav a.cn-nav-prev span{
background: #666 url(../images/prev.png) no-repeat center center;
}

.cn-nav a div{
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
overflow: hidden;
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
margin: 0px;
-moz-border-radius: 0px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px;
border-radius: 0px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

.cn-nav a:hover span{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
-moz-border-radius: 50px;
-webkit-border-radius: 50px;
border-radius: 50px;
opacity: 0.6;
margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
background-size: 22px 32px;
background-color:#a8872d;
}

.cn-nav a:hover div{
width: 90px;
height: 90px;
background-size: 120% 120%;
margin: -45px 0 0 -45px;
-moz-border-radius: 45px;
-webkit-border-radius: 45px;
border-radius: 45px;
}

</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="cn-nav">
<a href="#" class="cn-nav-prev">
<span>Previous</span>
<div style="background-image:url(images/1.jpg);"></div>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please link to your jsfiddle page...

Comment: @MarcAudet Forgot to save the jsfiddle example. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your span style set:

```
.cn-nav a span {
    overflow: hidden;
    ….
}
```

and remove `text-indent: -9000px;`

To make the text disappear, set the color equal to the background color on hover:

```
.cn-nav a:hover span {
    ...
    background-color:#a8872d;
    color: #a8872d;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jqEzZ/3/)

If you want the circle to pulsate, look at using an animation [(MDN Docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) for your hover rather than a simple transition.

Comment: Thanks! how can I make the initial circle bigger without getting out of proportion?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Do you mean big enough to show the span text initially?

Comment: Yes Correct, when trying to do so, it made the circle go out of proportion. In others words, have the text adapt to it perfectly in the center? here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/jqEzZ/6/

Comment: To keep a circle, you can use border-radius: 50% [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/jqEzZ/7/)  Does that get you closer?  For centering, since you are using margins to keep your transition ~centered, I don't know that you can.  I'll see if I can work up a demo that shows a different approach if you are ok with a change in markup.

Comment: @Code_Ed_Student [heres a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jqEzZ/9/) that uses a seperate element and scaling to expand.  That allows the span to stay in its original position.  Adding `text-align: center` will then keep its text centered.  This also simplifies your css as you no longer have to adjust margins, etc to get the effect.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to make it pulsate purely with CSS using CSS3 `animations`. [Learn more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations).

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q3gMS/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="cn-nav">
<a href="#" class="cn-nav-prev">
    <p>Click ME!</p>
<span></span>
<div style="background-image:url(images/1.jpg);"></div>
</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cn-nav > a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
}
a.cn-nav-prev {
    left: 0px;
}
a.cn-nav-next {
    right: 0px;
}
.cn-nav a span {
    width: 46px;
    height: 46px;
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9000px;
    border-radius: 23px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=90)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=90);
    opacity: 0.9;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-background-size: 17px 25px;
    -moz-background-size: 17px 25px;
    background-size: 17px 25px;
    margin: -23px 0 0 -23px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.cn-nav a p {
    display: block;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
}
.cn-nav a:hover p {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
}
.cn-nav a:hover span {
    -webkit-animation: pulsate 1s infinite;
    -moz-animation: pulsate 1s infinite;
    -ms-animation: pulsate 1s infinite;
    -o-animation: pulsate 1s infinite;
    animation: pulsate 1s infinite;
}
@keyframes "pulsate" {
 0% {
    background-color: #a8872d;
 }
 50% {
    background-color: red;
 }
 100% {
    background-color: #a8872d;
 }
}
@-moz-keyframes pulsate {
 0% {
   background-color: #a8872d;
 }
 50% {
   background-color: red;
 }
 100% {
   background-color: #a8872d;
 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes "pulsate" {
 0% {
   background-color: #a8872d;
 }
 50% {
   background-color: red;
 }
 100% {
   background-color: #a8872d;
 }
}
@-ms-keyframes "pulsate" {
 0% {
   background-color: #a8872d;
 }
 50% {
   background-color: red;
 }
 100% {
   background-color: #a8872d;
 }
}
@-o-keyframes "pulsate" {
 0% {
   background-color: #a8872d;
 }
 50% {
   background-color: red;
 }
 100% {
   background-color: #a8872d;
 }
}
.cn-nav a.cn-nav-prev span {
    background: #666 url(../images/prev.png) no-repeat center center;
}
.cn-nav a div {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
.cn-nav a:hover span {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    opacity: 0.6;
    margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
    -webkit-background-size: 22px 32px;
    -moz-background-size: 22px 32px;
    background-size: 22px 32px;
    background-color: #a8872d;
}
.cn-nav a:hover div {
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    -webkit-background-size: 120% 120%;
    -moz-background-size: 120% 120%;
    background-size: 120% 120%;
    margin: -45px 0 0 -45px;
    border-radius: 45px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see what kind of picture you are using as a background image but I have an idea on how to place the text inside of the circle and hide it on hover.
I think I would solve this using a pseudoelement since you can than place text inside of your link and center it as well.
On hover you could then just put opacity: 0 or empty the content (content: "";)

I did simplify the markup just to show you how I'd solve it with the pseudoelement.

http://dabblet.com/gist/6406590

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<a class="circle"></a>
```

**CSS**

```
.circle {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    background: #bada55;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.circle:after {
    content: "Hover Here";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 40%;
}
.circle:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);
    background: #82983b;
}
.circle:hover:after {
    content: "";
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/Gjx3Q/)**

For now, this just scales on hover and changes color. What did you mean by pulsate -- kinda like this? [Pulsate w/ Keyframes](http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/Gjx3Q/1/)